# Android InstrumentationTestCase on custom view using resource, not found

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-instrumentation

I have a custom view that creates Views dynamically.

```
public class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout {
    ...
    private View foo() {
        View view = new View(getContext());
        view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.gray));
        return view;
    }
}
```

And when I test foo(), I get a resource not found exception.

```
public class MyCustomViewTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {
    ...
    public void testFoo() {
        View view = myCustomView.foo();
        assertNotNull(view);
    }
}

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c0022
```

How can I get the test to see my color Resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible through getTargetContext(). I previously had

```
myCustomView = new MyCustomView(getInstrumentation().getContext());
```

and replaced it with

```
myCustomView = new MyCustomView(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext());
```